# apoc.periodic.iterate fails with exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, graphaware

I am trying run the annotation function of graphaware within Neo4J (see documentation [here](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-nlp/blob/master/README.md)). I have a set of 5000 nodes (KnowledgeArticles) with textual data in the content property. To annotate those I run the following query in Neo4J desktop:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (n:KnowledgeArticle) RETURN n",
"CALL ga.nlp.annotate({text: n.content, id: id(n)})
YIELD result MERGE (n)-[:HAS_ANNOTATED_TEXT]->(result)", {batchSize:1, iterateList:true})
```

After annotating approximately 200 to 300 KnowledgeArticles the database shuts down and provides the error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: 
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@373b81ee rejected from 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@285a2901[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 288]
```

I have experimented using different values for `batchSize` or setting `iterateList` to false, but none of this helped.
Also, I have tried performing the above `iterate` call limiting it only to 150 nodes. This works fine for the first time I call it, but when I perform it for a second time it again provides the same error, stating that the `completed_task` is about 200 to 300. The processor in the back thus seems to 'remember' the amount of tasks it has run in total as of the first time the database has started.

Could you help me resolve this issue. I want to run the above query not necessarily from Neo4j desktop, but eventually with py2neo from Python using `graph.run([iterate-query])`. If there is thus any way of solving this from Python, that would be even better.

Thank you!

PS. The debug log provides the following output (as of the last few iterations of the annotation up until the shut down):

```
2019-05-21 12:46:10.359+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.p.AnnotatedTextPersister] Start storing annotatedText 251906
2019-05-21 12:46:13.784+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.p.AnnotatedTextPersister] end storing annotatedText 251906. It took: 3425
2019-05-21 12:46:13.786+0000 INFO [c.g.n.e.EventDispatcher] Notifying listeners for event {}
2019-05-21 12:46:13.788+0000 INFO [c.g.n.e.EventDispatcher] Notifying listeners for event {}
2019-05-21 12:46:13.800+0000 INFO [c.g.n.u.ProcessorUtils] Taking default pipeline from configuration : myPipeline
2019-05-21 12:46:13.868+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.s.StanfordTextProcessor] Time for pipeline annotation (myPipeline): 67. Text length: 954
2019-05-21 12:46:13.869+0000 INFO [c.g.n.NLPManager] Time to annotate 68
2019-05-21 12:46:13.869+0000 INFO [c.g.n.e.EventDispatcher] Notifying listeners for event {}
2019-05-21 12:46:13.869+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.p.AnnotatedTextPersister] Start storing annotatedText 251907
2019-05-21 12:46:15.848+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.p.AnnotatedTextPersister] end storing annotatedText 251907. It took: 1978
2019-05-21 12:46:15.848+0000 INFO [c.g.n.e.EventDispatcher] Notifying listeners for event {}
2019-05-21 12:46:15.862+0000 INFO [c.g.n.e.EventDispatcher] Notifying listeners for event {}
2019-05-21 12:46:15.915+0000 INFO [c.g.n.u.ProcessorUtils] Taking default pipeline from configuration : myPipeline
2019-05-21 12:46:16.294+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.s.StanfordTextProcessor] Time for pipeline annotation (myPipeline): 378. Text length: 2641
2019-05-21 12:46:16.295+0000 INFO [c.g.n.NLPManager] Time to annotate 379
2019-05-21 12:46:16.296+0000 INFO [c.g.n.e.EventDispatcher] Notifying listeners for event {}
2019-05-21 12:46:16.296+0000 INFO [c.g.n.p.p.AnnotatedTextPersister] Start storing annotatedText 251908
2019-05-21 12:46:16.421+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database graph.db is unavailable.
2019-05-21 12:46:17.018+0000 INFO [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper] stopped
2019-05-21 12:46:17.020+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2019-05-21 12:46:17.149+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutting down 'graph.db' database.
2019-05-21 12:46:17.150+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2019-05-21 12:46:17.164+0000 INFO [o.n.b.i.BackupServer] BackupServer communication server shutting down and unbinding from  /127.0.0.1:6362
2019-05-21 12:46:17.226+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by database shutdown @ txId: 7720 checkpoint started...
2019-05-21 12:46:17.247+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] Rotated counts store at transaction 7720 to [/Users/{my.user.name}/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-e2babea7-0332-4c2c-bf1d-076d4feed49a/installation-3.5.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a], from [/Users/{my.user.name}/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-e2babea7-0332-4c2c-bf1d-076d4feed49a/installation-3.5.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b].
2019-05-21 12:46:17.644+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by database shutdown @ txId: 7720 checkpoint completed in 418ms
2019-05-21 12:46:17.647+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] No log version pruned, last checkpoint was made in version 3
2019-05-21 12:46:17.698+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2019-05-21 12:46:17.700+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2019-05-21 12:46:17.706+0000 INFO [c.g.r.BaseGraphAwareRuntime] Shutting down GraphAware Runtime... 
2019-05-21 12:46:17.709+0000 INFO [c.g.r.m.BaseModuleManager] Shutting down module UIDM
2019-05-21 12:46:17.709+0000 INFO [c.g.r.m.BaseModuleManager] Shutting down module NLP
2019-05-21 12:46:17.712+0000 INFO [c.g.r.s.RotatingTaskScheduler] Terminating task scheduler...
2019-05-21 12:46:17.712+0000 INFO [c.g.r.s.RotatingTaskScheduler] Task scheduler terminated successfully.
2019-05-21 12:46:17.714+0000 INFO [c.g.r.BaseGraphAwareRuntime] GraphAware Runtime shut down.
```

Comment: there is nothing more in the `debug.log` ?

Comment: @logisima Please see the update for the debug.log output. You were right to request that!